# Each item as a link in auto complete text view Yii

Tags: yii

I want to implement an auto complete text view with each array item as a link in Yii.

My Widget is

```
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',
                  array(
                      'name'=>'test1',
                      'value'=>'test21',
                      'source'=>$this->createUrl('user/autocompleteTest'),
                      'options'=>array(
                          'showAnim'=>'fold',
                       )
                  )
    );
?>
```

My controller function is

```
public function actionAutocomplete() 
{       
    $res =array();
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) 
    {           
        $qtxt ="SELECT USR_FirstName FROM {{Users}} WHERE USR_FirstName LIKE:USR_FirstName";
        $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
        $command->bindValue(":USR_FirstName", '%'.$_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $res =$command->queryColumn();
    }
    echo CJSON::encode($res);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Auto complete text view is working fine.

Now I want a link for the each item in the auto complete text view. How can I achieve this?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I want to implement a auto complete text view with each item in the auto text view as a link in yii. please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

You have to think that the autocomplete widget from Yii (and JUi) it's an input. The dropdown will be items that will populate that input.

If you need thinks, the autocomplete widget is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to implement search box for to search for friends like in facebook... thats y am asking for auto complete text view with each item as link....Thank you

Comment: You are looking for something like this http://www.web2ajax.fr/examples/facebook_searchengine/

Comment: Yeah am looking for the same.. Thank you.. Can u suggest the same feature is in yii.